# What is the set of stochastic processes that have a deterministic quadratic variation?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, quadratic-variation

It is know that the quadratic variation of Brownian motion $B_t$ is deterministic, $[B]_t=t$.

What other stochastic processes $X_t$ have a deterministic quadratic variation $f_X(t)$ ? Can we characterise this set ?

This set must include at least all process of the form $B_{g(t)}$ for any continuous $g: \mathbb R^+ \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$. What other elements are in this set ?

Comment: Are we considering only continuous local martingales, or any stochastic process?

Comment: Any stochastic process

Comment: It includes $N(t) -\lambda t$, where $N$ is a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins: I think you are not right. The quadratic variation of $X_t:=N_t-\lambda t$ is given by $[X]_t=N_t$, which is not deterministic.

Comment: You are correct — sorry!  I was thinking of $\langle X\rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I hope the following is an answer in the way you wanted it to be. If there are any mistakes in it, please correct me.*

As far as I know, the quadratic variation is only defiened for semimartingales, so we just consider this type of process. As $[X]_0=X_0^2$ we need $|X_0|$ to be deterministic. For simplicity let's focus first on continous processes. Since semimartingales are sums of local martingales and FV-processes, and since the continuous part of the quadratic variation is zero for FV-processes, we can always add a continuous FV-process to any stochastic process with a deterministic quadratic variation without destroying this property. As all contiuous local martingales are [time-changed Brownian motions](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/04/20/time-changed-brownian-motion/#scn_tc_thm1)
and since their quadratic variation is the change-of-time, the set contains all time-changed Brownian motions with a deterministic change-of-time (it might sound a bit silly, but this seems to be the answer). Now consider the discontinuous part. As the jumps of the quadratic variation are exactly the squared jumps of the process $\Delta [X]_t=(\Delta X_t)^2$ we need to have deterministic jumps. In summary the set (Hint: This is not unique decomposition.) consists of all processes
$$X=M+A+J$$
(with a deterministic value $|X_0|$), where $M$ is a time-changed Brownian motions with a deterministic change-of-time, $A$ is a continuous FV-process and $J$ is a deterministic pure jump process. $\big($I'm not sure about this: As a non-constant deterministic pure jump process can't be a local martingale, the process $J$ can be included in the (noncontinuous) FV-part, thus $X$ is the sum of a a time-changed Brownian motions with a deterministic change-of-time and a FV-process with deterministic jumps.$\big)$

Another way to look at this is to consider [purely discontinuous semimartingales](https://almostsuremath.com/2016/08/14/purely-discontinuous-semimartingales/). These are sums of FV-processes and purely discontinuous local martingales, which means that continuous part of the quadratic variation ist zero. As every semimartingale $X$ [decomposes uniquely](https://almostsuremath.com/2016/08/14/purely-discontinuous-semimartingales/#scn_pds_thm11) as $$X=X^c+X^d,$$
where $X^c$ is a continuous local martingale with ${X^c_0=0}$ and ${X^d}$ is a purely discontinuous semimartingale, the desired set consists of processes $X$ (with a deterministic value $|X_0|$) which are the sum of a purely discontinuous semimartingale with deterministic jumps and a time-changed Brownian motion with a deterministic change-of-time.

Comment: So if we restrict to continuous semimartingale, the deterministic time changes of Brownian motion are the only ones ? I do not understand your initial discussion on $X_0$, what if it is not $0$ ?

Comment: If we restrict to continuous semimartingales, the sums $X=M+A$ of continuous FV-processes $A$ and deterministic time changes of Brownian motions $M$ are the only ones. Sry, the $X_0=0$-part came up while creating this text and after changing some things it became redundant. I will remove it. But the deterministic initial value is necessary.

Comment: You brought me just now to the insight, that there is an exception of $X_0$ being deterministic. Just $X_0^2$ hast to be deterministic, this means if $X_0$ only takes values of the set $\{+x,-x\}$, $x\in\mathbb R$ it can depend on $\omega$. I will add it to the answer.